# How to transfer an str Series into a two dimensional ndarray?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyezN.png)

this is my data

and I wanna transfer it into a two dimensional ndarray, I have tried many methods, like np.from_string, pd.pd.to_numeric, but I can't solve it

Comment: Please add code, errors and data as **text** ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing.  Images should only be used, *in addition to text in code format*, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `list comprehension` with `split` and converting to `np.array`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'pixels':['70 80 82 72','151 1050 147 155']})
print (df)
             pixels
0       70 80 82 72
1  151 1050 147 155

arr = np.array([x.split() for x in df['pixels']]).astype(int)
print (arr)
[[  70   80   82   72]
 [ 151 1050  147  155]]
```

If data in file:

```
arr = np.genfromtxt('my_file.csv', delimiter=' ', dtype=np.int64)
print(arr)
[[  70   80   82   72]
 [ 151 1050  147  155]]
```

Comment: @ducklu - How was created `DataFrame` ?

Comment: I download the data in an image database for the emotion recognition

Comment: @ducklu - link is possible see?

Comment: it's fer_2013 from Kaggle, but I forget the link, sorry